# Python regex findall numbers and dots

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm using re.findall() to extract some version numbers from an HTML file:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "<table><td><a href=\"url\">Test0.2.1.zip</a></td><td>Test0.2.1</td></table> Test0.2.1"
>>> re.findall("Test([\.0-9]*)", text)
['0.2.1.', '0.2.1', '0.2.1']
```

but I would like to only get the ones that do not end in a dot.
The filename might not always be .zip so I can't just stick .zip in the regex.

I wanna end up with:

```
['0.2.1', '0.2.1']
```

Can anyone suggest a better regex to use? :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
re.findall(r"Test([0-9.]*[0-9]+)", text)
```

or, a bit shorter:

```
re.findall(r"Test([\d.]*\d+)", text)
```

By the way - you do not need to escape the dot in a character class. Inside `[]` the `.` has no special meaning, it just matches a literal dot. Escaping it has no effect.

Comment: It should probably be \d+ if numbers can be greater than 9

Comment: It should be r"Test([\d.]*\d+)" -- \d doesn't mean anything in the string so it works, but generally it's good practice not to rely on that.

You could do r"Test(\d*(?:\.\d+))" if you want to be slightly more restrictive (rejecting 1..2, for instance)